# How to do the mapping to update an existing entity, while allowing to set property values in destination to null?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have an Identity 2.0 User with some custom fields and in order to update them I can do manual mapping like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UserProfile([Bind(Include = "FullName,Gender,DateBirth")] ApplicationUser model)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    // do stuff... validation...

    user.FullName = model.FullName;
    user.Gender = model.Gender;
    user.DateBirth = model.DateBirth;

    await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

I'm going to add at least 10 more fields, so I tried using AutoMapper like this:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

// Ignore id
Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUser>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Id, m => m.Ignore());
Mapper.Map(model, user);

await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

AutoMapper is setting all fields inexistent in model to null, e.g. Email, Password, etc are being set to null. I.e. it is overwriting the existing user completely. So I tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUser>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Id, m => m.Ignore())
    .ForAllMembers(a => a.Condition(s => !s.IsSourceValueNull));
```

But with that if I set a property as null in model, the existing user will not be updated and will keep the original value (FullName and Gender can be null). It only updates if model has a non null value, if the value is null, it will keep existing user value for the field.

**How to do the mapping to update an existing entity, while allowing to set existing values to null?**

**UPDATE #1:** for some reason now after mapping model to user, the email property is being set to: *AppName.Models.ApplicationUser*. That means the email is being set to the ApplicationUser namespace. (I didn't change anything, and I'm not sending a new email from the form).

**UPDATE #2:** Creating a ViewModel and having a simple mapping like this solved the issue:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>().
```

Thing is: **is it possible to accomplish what I want without a ViewModel?** This way keeping my original problem and question.